Flutter PopScope(child: Scaffold(), canPop: false) does not disable left and right gesture navigation in app
I want to disable left and right gesture navigation for 1 page ( one dart program) in my app which is 21 dart programs.   I do not care about the other pages. I have not found any simple examples that work on my pixel 8 phone.
The app compiles and works fine but I cannot disable the left and right gestures on the pixel 8 phone on which I am testing.    If I add the line of code
 PopScope(child: Scaffold(), canPop: false);
in the widget build override, it makes no difference - the left and right gestures are still not disabled.
Here is my code for Page6.dart (with many of the 300 lines removed for simplicity)....

class Page6 extends StatefulWidget {

...(code)

  @override
  State<Page6> createState() => _Page6State();
}

class _Page6State extends State<Page6> {

...(code)

  @override
  void initState() {

...(code)

  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    PopScope(child: Scaffold(), canPop: false);
    ManTrack mantrack = widget.mantrack;
    RouteDataModel routeNow = widget.routeNow;
    TransformationController viewTC = widget.viewTC;
    print('page6.dart - build method called, ok = $ok');
    t.timestamp('#3 ***** START BUILD *******');
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      t.timestamp("#999 **** BUILD COMPLETE *******");
    });
    if (ok && mantrack.uiShow != null) {
      return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
              title: const Text("Tracking You"),
              automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
              actions: [
                ElevatedButton(
                    child: Text('Refresh'),
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      getLocationNow();
                    }),
                ElevatedButton(
                    child: Text('Save'),
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      p6popup2(context, routeNow, mantrack);
                    }),
                ElevatedButton(
                    child: Text('Stats'),
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.orange),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      MapCornersDataModel2 mapcornersNow = widget.mapcornersNow;
                      GPSLocation gpsNow = widget.gpsNow;
                      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => Page5(
                                mapcornersNow: mapcornersNow,
                                gpsNow: gpsNow,
                                statsNow: statsNow,
                                t: t,
                              )));
                    }),
                ElevatedButton(
                    child: Text('Stop'),
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      p6popup1(context, routeNow, mantrack);
                    })
              ]),
          body: InteractiveViewer(
              transformationController: viewTC,
              minScale: 0.5,
              maxScale: 100.0,
              child: RawImage(
                  image: mantrack.uiShow,
                  height: double.infinity,
                  width: double.infinity)));
    } else {
      return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    }
  }
}



you don't insert PopScope anywhere in the widgets tree: it just "hangs" not attached to anything (the first line of _Page6State.build method)

Thanks. Now I see the issue.    It is now fixed and working by placing PopScope within the return so it is now part of the tree.

As noted in the comments, the line of code
PopScope(child: Scaffold(), canPop: false);

does not reference the widget build Scaffold.   It must be removed.   The correct and working code is below....
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
ManTrack mantrack = widget.mantrack;
RouteDataModel routeNow = widget.routeNow;
TransformationController viewTC = widget.viewTC;
print('page6.dart - build method called, ok = $ok');
t.timestamp('#3 ***** START BUILD *******');
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  t.timestamp("#999 **** BUILD COMPLETE *******");
});
if (ok && mantrack.uiShow != null) {
  return PopScope(
      canPop: false,
      child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
              title: const Text("Tracking You"),
              automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
              actions: [
                ElevatedButton(
                    child: Text('Refresh'),
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      getLocationNow();
                    }),
                ElevatedButton(
                    child: Text('Save'),
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      p6popup2(context, routeNow, mantrack);
                    }),
                ElevatedButton(
                    child: Text('Stats'),
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.orange),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      MapCornersDataModel2 mapcornersNow =
                          widget.mapcornersNow;
                      GPSLocation gpsNow = widget.gpsNow;
                      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => Page5(
                                mapcornersNow: mapcornersNow,
                                gpsNow: gpsNow,
                                statsNow: statsNow,
                                t: t,
                              )));
                    }),
                ElevatedButton(
                    child: Text('Stop'),
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      p6popup1(context, routeNow, mantrack);
                    })
              ]),
          body: InteractiveViewer(
              transformationController: viewTC,
              minScale: 0.5,
              maxScale: 100.0,
              child: RawImage(
                  image: mantrack.uiShow,
                  height: double.infinity,
                  width: double.infinity))));
} else {
  return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
}

}
}
